# If loop with many OR conditions

Tags: php, mysql, loops, if-statement, mysqli

I have two tables. Both with same structure. Only one has a dump of data (table1) and the other has only unique data (table2). I want to use loop and update table2. If new data is found then insert new row in table2 else update the existing row in table2.
Below is my code: 
$data_pts: array containing the data of table1.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs_select_ptsdata_replica))
{

    $temp = 0;
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($data_pts); $i++)
    {
        if( $row['app_SlNo'] == $data_pts[$i][1])
        {
            if( $row['pts_ProjectNum'] == $data_pts[$i][3])
            {
                if( $row['pts_ReleaseDate'] == $data_pts[$i][6])
                {
       /*If any of the below condition doesnt match then the loop should execute*/
                    if( ($data_pts[$i][9] != $row['pts_DTVResources']) ||         
                        ($data_pts[$i][10] != $row['pts_IBMPrep']) ||
                        ($data_pts[$i][11] != $row['pts_IBMExec']) ||   
                        ($data_pts[$i][12] != $row['pts_DTVContractors']) ||
                        ($data_pts[$i][13] != $row['pts_IBMTnM']) || 
                        ($data_pts[$i][14] != $row['pts_IBMAS']))
                    {
                        $temp ++; // if any hour doesn't match the table1 data compared to table2 data. 
                        break;
                    }

                    else 
                    {
                        echo "hours not same<br/>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            $temp = 0; // Every hours is same as in table1 and table2
            break;
        }
    }

    if($temp > 0)
    {
        $sql_update_pts = "update ".$db.".tbl_ptsdata set 
                          pts_projectname ='".$row[7]."', 
                          pts_commit_status = '".$row[8]."',
                          pts_dtvresources = '".$row[9]."', 
                          pts_ibmprep = '".$row[10]."',
                          pts_ibmexec = '".$row[11]."', 
                          pts_dtvcontractors = '".$row[12]."',
                          pts_ibmtnm = '".$row[13]."', 
                          pts_ibmas = '".$row[14]."'
                                  where app_slno = '".$row[1]."' and
                                  pts_applicationname = '".$row[2]."' and
                                  pts_projectnum = '".$row[3]."' and
                                  pts_chargeto = '".$row[4]."' and
                                  pts_crnum = '".$row[5]."' and
                                  pts_releasedate = '".$row[6]."'";
        $rs_insert_pts = $mysqli->query($sql_update_pts);
    }
    else if($temp == 0) /*If table1 data is not present in table2,insert in table2*/
    {
        $sql_insert_pts = "insert into ".$db.".tbl_ptsdata values('',                  
                            '".$row[1]."','".$row[2]."','".$row[3]."',
                            '".$row[4]."','".$row[5]."',
                            '".date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row[6]))."',
                            '".$row[7]."','".$row[8]."','".$row[9]."',
                            '".$row[10]."','".$row[11]."',
                            '".$row[12]."','".$row[13]."','".$row[14]."')";
        $rs_insert_pts = $mysqli->query($sql_insert_pts);
    }

    else if($temp == 2)
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem that I am facing is if suppose any one value in the if condition is not matching it is supposed to enter the loop, but its not happening.

Comment: I have a condition where many types of hours are present. If any hour value doesn't match from table1 and table2, then I will update all the values in the row of table2 from table1.